# Twilio javascript. hourglass shows every few seconds

Tags: twilio

When we activate a Twilio Client connection using Javascript library, every few seconds the hourglass icon shows up in the pointer. If we destroy the session via code and then reconnect it, the hourglass does not show any more. But a reload of the page brings the problem back.  The periodic hourglass distracts the user. Is there any way to turn it off? 
We have tried it in Chrome, Edge and Firefox under Windows, with similar results.
The problem does not occurr in OSX Chrome or Safari

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. I'd suggest you try profiling the JavaScript on your page and see what might be causing the hourglass to show up. If it is within Twilio Client then I would report that via the [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) team.

Comment: Thanks. Profiling confirmed it is within the Twilio Client. Twilio support has not provided a solution so I asked here to see if there is a programming solution to prevent the hourglass icon to appear every few seconds

Comment: Did you try sending your profiling data to the support team to pass on to the Client team?